# How to Sort all lines between two patterns in a file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a text file in which there are lines which need to be sorted between two patterns.

I am writing Perl script but does not seem to produce result.

Input file is shown below:

```
BEGIN
This is line10
This is line3
This is line15
...
END
BEGIN
This is line50
This is line12
This is line400
...
END
```

Note:
All the lines between pattern `BEGIN` and `END` needs to be sorted. Any pointer for Perl script regarding this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to parse data between `BEGIN` and `END`?

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Getting the parts between delimeters? For that you can use the .. flip-flop operator. For sorting with a custom sort function? You just pass a callback to the sort builtin. I can help, I just need to know with what

Comment: Thanks. I could get parts between delimiters as below.                                                 if (/BEGIN/ ... /END/){
      print "$_ \n";
  }

Comment: Sorting needs to be limited to a specific part.

Comment: Sorting needs to be done on 5th column of line in the part such as below                               sort { $a->[5] cmp $b->[5] } @lines;

Comment: @user419534 what is the fifth column in your example lines? Do you want numerical sort or lexical sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'if ($inside) {
              if (/END/) {
                  print sort {
                      ($a =~ /(\d+)/)[0] <=> ($b =~ /(\d+)/)[0]
                  } splice @buffer;
                  print;
              } else { push @buffer, $_ }
          } else {
              print;
              $inside = 1 if /BEGIN/;
          }' -- input-file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line, running the code for each line
- The variable `$inside` is true if we're inside a block between the patterns
- For lines inside the block, we don't print them, but instead store in an array, see [push](http://p3rl.org/push)
- On the last line of a block, we remove the stored lines from the array, sort them by numbers they contain (or whatever else you need) and print. See [splice](http://p3rl.org/splice), [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort). Then we print the END pattern line.
- Outside the pattern block, we simply print the lines. If we encounter the BEGIN pattern there, we set the flag $inside to 1 to start processing the block.

Comment: You probably want to use `-l`. Otherwise, `foo␉bar` will be sorted before `foo` (where "␉" is a tab).

Comment: Sort::Key::Natural's `natsort` would be a good choice for sorting arbitrary lines.

Comment: @ikegami: Simplified by removing the flip-flop. The sorting is just an example, as the OP didn't specify how to sort the lines exactly.

Comment: Yup, just tips for the OP or whoever.

Answer (score 2):

The following perl script works. Pass the input files as arguments.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @line;

while (<>) {
    push @line, $_ if (/BEGIN/.../END/);
    if(/END/ && @line) {
            chomp @line;
            print "$_$/" for sort @line[1..$#a-1];
            @line = ();
    }
    print if /BEGIN|END/;
}
```

This sorts lexically on full lines.
Please clarify the sort criteria or modify it as per your need.

Comment: I was wondering how to grep all lines if both BEGIN and END patterns are identical such as.                                                                                                                    BEGIN  
This is line10.   
This is line3. 
This is line15. 
...  
END.

Comment: @user419534 To make this code work when your begin pattern and end pattern are same use three dots instead of two between `/BEGIN/` and `/END/`. And replace `/END/` inside `if` condition with `/END/ && @line`. (I've updated the answer with these changes. Also, It is not clear what you mean by "grep" here.)